# Microsoft intermediate language code [MSIL] for array passing and return

Tags: c#, cil

I have created a dynamic method using MethodBuilder with the signature
        Int32[] Exp(Int32[])

The emitted code is as follows

```
Type[] myMthdParams = new Type[1];
myMthdParams[index] = typeof(int[]);
MethodBuilder myMthdBld = myTypeBld.DefineMethod("Exp",MethodAttributes.Public |MethodAttributes.Static, typeof(int[]),mthdParams);                                           
ILGenerator ILout = myMthdBld.GetILGenerator();
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);            
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);    
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

The method i want to implement is as follows:

```
int[] Exp(int[] arr)
{
    return arr;
}
```

I am getting the error CLR detected an invalid program.
What is it I am doing it wrong??
Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the whole code that involves the `MethodBuilder`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `stloc` and `ldloc` store into and then load from the first local. It's a bit like your code being:

```
int[] Exp(int[] arr)
{
    var temp = arr;
    return temp;
}
```

But if you haven't defined that `temp` using `DeclareLocal()` then it's more like:

```
int[] Exp(int[] arr)
{
    temp = arr;
    return temp;
}
```

Which of course is invalid (no definition of `temp`).

You don't need this temporary local anyway (though debug compilations of C# will often include them to aid debugging). Why not just:

```
ILGenerator ILout = myMthdBld.GetILGenerator();
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);            
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Or if the method is static (and therefore doesn't have `this` as the first argument):

```
ILGenerator ILout = myMthdBld.GetILGenerator();
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);            
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Comment: This worked. It is a static method. So worked with Ldarg_0. Thanks a lot!